# What weights should I use while back-propagating?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, backpropagation

I've started to learn about neural networks recently and I can't find the answer to this question.

Let's assume there's a neural network (fig. 1)
[image: Figure 1]

So if the loss function is:
[image: Loss function]

and the derivative [image: deriv] is:
[image: Derivative definition]

if I want to use this to find [image: dE/dw122] what *k* and *l* (well there's only one neuron with index *l* here, but what if there would be more?) should i use in [image: w^3_kl] and [image: w^2_jk]?

I've also found "other" way of backpropagating it's described [here](https://www.ibu.edu.ba/assets/userfiles/it/2012/eee-ANN-5.pdf), but I can't understand how they came up with that method from the original equation `w -= step * dE/dw`.

Sorry if I failed to explain my problem. If something isn't clear please ask in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will assume you notate $y$ as the models output and $z$ as the ground-truth. Second, I am assuming this is a linear model (No activation functions). Then the gradient math goes as so:

$
\begin{align*}
\frac{dE}{dw_{ij}^1} &= \frac{dE}{dy}\frac{dy}{dw_{ij}^1} \\
&= \frac{dE}{dy}\sum_k\frac{\partial y}{\partial n_{k}^3}\frac{dn_{k}^3}{dw_{ij}^1} \\
&= \frac{dE}{dy}\sum_k\frac{\partial y}{\partial n_{k}^3} \frac{\partial n_{k}^3}{ \partial n_{j}^2} \frac{dn_{j}^2}{ dw_{ij}^1}  \\
&= -2*(z-y)\sum_kw_{kl}^3w_{jk}^2 x_i  \\ 
\end{align*}
$

So the reason you are having trouble to figure out which $k$ index to use, the answer is because you need to use both and sum over them. The $l$ index is just the only $l$ index that exists because you only have one node in that layer.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to learn more about derivatives apparently. I would up-vote but I don't have enough reputation, sorry.

Comment: @Sharpy glad to help and there are tons of online resource going over the differential calculus if you need the refresher, Also if it answered your question, you can still checkmark the answer as correct even if you cant upvote